# Error trying to remove index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-localdb

I'm new in SQL and I'm practicing some exercises using Microsoft SQL Server. I created this index and then I'm trying to drop the index but it says that it is not a constraint. But custID column SHOWS THAT IT is the PRIMARY KEY.

This is what I did:

```
CREATE INDEX indexcustInfoID ON tblCustomerIDInfo (CustID) 

ALTER TABLE tblCustomerIDInfo 
DROP CONSTRAINT indexcustInfoID
```

Error:

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
>   'indexcustInfoID' is not a constraint.
>
> Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 26
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Please help me!

Comment: You do not need to add an index on the primary key - one will be created automatically.

Comment: Ohh I got it. I was following a video in which they use MySQL and the guy did like that, but i'm using sql server. Is there any difference between both when creating and dropping index?

Answer (score 2):

You want `DROP INDEX` instead of `DROP CONSTRAINT`. `DROP CONSTRAINT` only applies to indexes created for primary keys and `UNIQUE` constraints.  It sounds like you've added *another* index on the primary key column, which is not the primary key constraint itself.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx):

> The DROP INDEX statement does not apply to indexes created by defining PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints. To remove the constraint and corresponding index, use ALTER TABLE with the DROP CONSTRAINT clause.